# Android layout inspector view values in pixel

Tags: android

I want to view the values in pixel in layout inspector. Is it possible? Right now I am able to view only values in dp. So I am manually convert the dp value to pixel using of the following formula.

```
dp * densityDpi / 160;
```

Or I am using some online tool to validate the values in pixel. Is it possible to view in the Android layout inspector?